# Difference between Stationary and Non-Stationary time series

Tags: python, pytorch, time-series, transformer-model

What is the Difference between Stationary and Non-Stationary time series?

this link :[https://blog.quantinsti.com/stationarity/#:~:text=A%20stationary%20time%20series%20has,to%20the%20long%2Drun%20mean.&text=A%20time%20series%20whose%20statistical%20properties%20change%20over%20time%20is,is%20non%2Dstationary%20in%20nature](https://blog.quantinsti.com/stationarity/#:%7E:text=A%20stationary%20time%20series%20has,to%20the%20long%2Drun%20mean.&text=A%20time%20series%20whose%20statistical%20properties%20change%20over%20time%20is,is%20non%2Dstationary%20in%20nature).
explain it
but in a simple way with example, what is it?
I can't understand it because ,I want to find out Why is stationarity one of the key components in time series analysis?
are we have any other type of time series?

Answer (score 0):

In the context of machine learning (you tagged your question with "pytorch"):

1. Stationary time series: the time does not matter so you can make the prediction of a frame from the input frame and no other frame can bring more information (independance of time frames). The number of the frame (the time) is not a relevant information.
   Then, shuffling all your data change nothing.

ex: you have a serie of 10 pictures of cats and dogs and want to predict if it is a cat or a dog -> for a given picture, the other pictures doesn't matter.

2. Non-stationary time series: the other frames bring information to make a prediction on each frame. You should to keep the order of the frames. By default, a "time serie" is by definition in this category.

ex: you capture the velocity of someone at each seconds and you want to predict the next speed. Here the past is important.